# SikuliX cannot detect a screen

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I have got a problem trying to run SikuliX script remotely. The thing is, when I call the script from cmd line without starting an IDE, the script works fine. However, when I call the script using the same command remotely from the website, the script says that there is no screen:

`[error] Location: outside any screen (2413888, 2413888) - subsequent actions might not work as expected)`

Is there a way I could specify what screen SikuliX is supposed to use? I assumed it should be operating on the screen when it was installed.

Comment: the answer is probably highly dependant on the OS you are running on.

Comment: the OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first you can try to check the number of screen detected by SikuliX script by the following code:

```
print Screen.getNumberScreens()
```